# Get all locations of Panoramio photos in a given extent

Tags: api, geolocation, density, photos, landscape

To create a visual quality heat map I'm trying to get a list of all Panoramio photos in an about 2000 Km2 wide study area. My idea is to perform a density analysis in GIS on a point shapefile including all the photo locations. I've used the well-known Panoramio syntax to get the coordinates:

```
http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=full&from=0&to=499&minx=12.068&miny=42.921&maxx=12.577&maxy=43.371&size=medium&mapfilter=false
```

But I've encountered two kind of problems:

1. Every single output seems limited to 498 records (not only 100 as declared by Panoramio..)
2. The number of photos seems reduced automatically depending on the bounding rectangle extents, so not all the photos within the area are returned even setting consecutive from-to ranges.

So a possible solution could be to loop the query according to a moving window approach (let's say 0.01x0.01 deg wide) and to merge the results.

Unfortunately I don't have experience on programming...
Any suggestion about how to do this?